# omnet++ : what is penguin mode in tkenv, qtenv animation settings?

Tags: omnet++, veins

i noticed the penguin mode in tkenv makes my omnet++ (version 5.0) simulation crash (preferences->animation->messages->penguin mode).
This doest not happen with qtenv.

I don't know what means this penguin mode : does anyone know?

Thank you.
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Penguin mode is an easter egg (or prank, depending how you see it) in OMNeT++. It basically changes the dots that are passed between the modules to penguin icons (so you will see a lot of birds migrating between the modules :). If it crashes on TKEnv, we definitely have to fix it as it is a bug :)

Comment: I've reported the bug. It seems Tkenv doesn't find the penguin icon as it is replaced by interrogative symbols. Thank you for the answer.